# create include file using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a folder containing hpp and cpp files. I need to create a header file that includes all hpp files in the said folder:

```
#pragma once
#include "test_1.hpp"
#include "test_2.hpp"
#include "test_3.hpp"
```

can CMake do that?

Note:I am not going to put 'my' research work on your shoulder. I just need to know if such thing is possible, and possibly a link to where I can read from. My initial googling didn't show anything useful. 
thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `configure_file` to fill a variable inside a template file. Create a template file containing the outline of the desired file and a placeholder for your include statements, e.g.:

**list.hpp.in**

```
#pragma once
@include_statements@
```

Then, in your **CMakeLists.txt**, you can fill the placeholder `@include_statements@` with a list of files wrapped with `#include` statements.

```sh
project(test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# Get list of some *.hpp files in folder include 
file(GLOB include_files include/*.hpp)

# Convert the list of files into #includes
foreach(include_file ${include_files})
  set(include_statements "${include_statements}#include \"${include_file}\"\n")
endforeach()

# Fill the template    
configure_file(list.hpp.in list.hpp)
```

Comment: a common practice is to add the .in extension to the template that cmake uses. In your case configure_file(list.hpp.in list.hpp) It makes it easier to relate the input with the output.

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution requires running CMake to reflect any new files added to the include directory.

Comment: @Andrzej thanks, it works. `include_files` in CMakeLists.txt` includes absolute path. Is there any way to use the relative path?

Comment: Sure, check out the RELATIVE option of the file command http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html